# Read only one line of txt in C

Tags: c, ansi-c

I want to read the first line of one txt file and save it to hexArray.

The line contains 32 characters representing a hexadecimal number.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "gmp.h"

char *saveToArray(FILE *hexFile);

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    char ch;
    FILE *hexFile = fopen("hex.txt", "rb"); //recebido pela consola
    char *hexArray = saveToArray(hexFile);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 32; i++)
    {       
        printf("%c", hexArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%d", sizeof hexArray);

    ch = getchar();
    return 0;
}

char *saveToArray(FILE *hexFile)
//metodo que devolve uma array contendo uma linha do ficheiro
{
    char hexArray[32];
    fgets(hexArray, sizeof hexArray, hexFile);  
    return hexArray;
}
```

It seems to be okay, but the output shows that it isn't.

Please help me solve this.

Thanks!
Cumps.

Comment: What do you see in the output?
What do you expect to see in the output?

Comment: You're returning the address of the automatic variable `hexArray` that goes out of scope when `saveToArray` exits, and with that invoking *undefined behavior*  by dereferencing that address later.

Comment: PROBLEM: "char hexArray[]" is valid *ONLY INSIDE YOUR* "saveToArray()" function.  Q: You know the string needs to be terminated with "null", correct?  So at most, you can read only 31 characters - and possibly less, if there's a newline in your "fgets()" input.  PROBLEM: You *must* insure the string is property terminated.

Comment: You should never return an address to local variables in your functions in C. It will always break. The same is true for local arrays and local structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make `hexArray` `static` either by doing this:

```
char *saveToArray(FILE *hexFile)
//metodo que devolve uma array contendo uma linha do ficheiro
{ 
    static char hexArray[32];
    fgets(hexArray, sizeof hexArray, hexFile);  
    return hexArray;
}
```

Or, by doing this:

```
char hexArray[32];
int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    char ch;
    ...
```

Comment: RESOLVED
i'm new in C. it was a noob mistake.
thank you very much

Comment: +1 or make `hexArray` automatic to the *caller* and passed as a formal parameter by-address works as well. `char * saveToArray(FILE* fp, char *dst, size_t maxlen);`

Comment: @WhozCraig That's also a very good idea.  Probably better actually.

Comment: @WhozCraig Are you purposely keeping your number of answers at 666? :-o

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey LOL. I never even noticed. How funny. No, i'm not. Your answer was correct and informative, so there is not reason to post a similar one when all I can offer is an addendum.